# Eclipse, Spring, Wildfly log4j logging

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

I am running Spring framework 3.2.2.RELEASE on WildFly 8.0. I am trying to get logging to work. I have tried reading several tutorials, but, can not seem to get any output to the console or log. I am looking at the console in Eclipse, and the log at wildfly/standalone/log/server.log.  Any help getting logging going is appreciated.

Here are some pieces of interesting code:

src/main/resources/log4j.xml:

```
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Application Loggers -->
<logger name="com.myCompany.myPackage">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>
    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers 
         omitted
    -->
<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c
] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c]
(%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
```

src/com/myCompany/myPackage/mySubpackage/myClass.java

```
package com.myCompany.myPackage.mySubpackage;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class myClass
{
   private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(myClass.class.getName());

   public SoccerFeed someMethod()
   {
      log.info("******************* someMethod ");
   }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**
Based on Jame's answer below, To fix this based on my setup above, I added the following to wildFly's standalone.xml, and logging works as expected:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
    <use-deployment-logging-config value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure how Spring configures logging, but I think it does something specific with log4j. You might need to disable the [`use-deployment-logging-config`](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-%7B%7Busedeploymentloggingconfig%7D%7D) to `false`. This will only configure logging for your deployment though.

You could also leave the `log4j.xml` configuration file out of your deployment and use the logging subsystem to configure logging.

Comment: I am not stuck on log4j. How I log is not important, just the ability to log is what I am after. I am new to Spring and Jboss/Wildfly. Is there a better/preferred way to do logging in this environment?

Comment: IMO it's better to use a logging facade like JBoss Logging or SLF4J. log4j is a full log manager which isn't generally needed in a container as the container should control logging.